# Create a circuit based on a graph

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

Let's say I have a graph,

[image]

and from this graph I want to create a circuit $K$ whose inputs can be set so that $K$ outputs true iff the graph has an independent set of size $\ge2.$

I've seen some decent stuff on the interent / youtube about how to go about this. But I was wondering if there is a standard set of steps one should follow on how to do this.

Comment: Your circuit can take edges as input, and output 1 (true) if at least one edge is missing (as this edge is an independent set). In general, your circuit can "or" together the edges in any subgraph of size $k$ and output true if at least one of these subgraphs is empty

Comment: @mm8511 So you wouldn't use 3-SAT or cirSat? you should draw it out. I'm interested now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a circuit for computing whether or not a graph on 6 vertices has a traingle. Note that the inputs are the edges of the graph, and are assumed to be boolean (1 indicating that an edge is present, and 0 o.w.) The edges are fed into the "gates" in the bottom. Each gate represents a subgraph containing the edges in it. In this case you are considering complete/empty subgraphs, so the "gates" will and together the edge bits. The circuit below can be simplified, but in general, it will have on the order of $\dbinom{n}{k}$ gates for computing whether or not a graph has a complete/empty subgraph of order $k$.
[image]

note that the bottom gates should be "or'd" together, I left this out for illustrative purposes.

Here is a circuit for computing whether or not a graph on 6 vertices has a complete/empty graph on 4 vertices

[image]

as you can imagine, these circuits get messy pretty quickly.

If you are interested in actually building circuits for this task, then I recommend checking out "Binary Decision Diagrams" or their closely related 'cousin', "Zero-Suppressed Binary Decision Diagrams." These are basically "Dynamic Programming" circuits, for lack of a better word. They exploit the repeated substructure of larger un-reduced circuits and can compress quite well for most practical purposes. They are used extensively in database design.